# Sonata admin : list always use defaut language

Tags: symfony, translation, sonata-admin, sonata

I use sonata admin bundle with Symfony 3.4 and knplabs. Everything work fine excepted one thing.

I have create a Test class and the sonata list with the CRUD.
This class has a translatable title, when I'm on the edit mode of one on my test object, I can click on the flag for editing the title in many languages.

But when I'm on my list view, the flag are display but when I click on it, the list always display the title in english (default language).

I debug and find that in edit view,  method setLocale and getLocal are used to change the languages but in list view, they are not call.

How can I translate my entites in my list view ?

Here my test class, translation test class and my testAdmin.

Test.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;
use Sonata\TranslationBundle\Model\TranslatableInterface;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TestRepository")
*/
class Test implements TranslatableInterface
    {
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $is_enable;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->translate(null, false)->getTitle();
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->translate(null, false)->setTitle($title);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsEnable(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->is_enable;
    }

    public function setIsEnable(bool $is_enable): self
    {
        $this->is_enable = $is_enable;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $locale
     */
    public function setLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->setCurrentLocale($locale);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocale()
    {
        return $this->getCurrentLocale();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     *
     * Set this to have a correct name display on BO (sonata translation add some weird id key after the name)
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        if (empty($this->getTitle())){
            return '';
        }
        else{
            return $this->getTitle();
        }
    }
}
```

TestTranslation.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="test_translation")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class TestTranslation
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return TestTranslation
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

TestAdmin.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;

class TestAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected $baseRoutePattern = 'test';
    protected $baseRouteName = 'test';

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('title', TextType::class)
            ->add('is_enable', TextType::class)
        ;
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id')
            ->add('title')
            ->add('is_enable')
            ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                'actions' => array(
                    'edit' => array(),
                    'delete' => array(),
                )
            ))
        ;
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper->add('id');
        $datagridMapper->add('translations.title', null, array('label' => 'Title'));
        $datagridMapper->add('is_enable');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return (string)$this->getTranslations()->get($locale);
```

use above code in __toString method Test.php

Comment: This is not my problem, __toString is not call in the list view and your code make error in my add and edit form

Comment: __tostring is called in list view 
have you write it in entity class?

Comment: that was just a hint you have to use it as you want to use
this is working on my 2 projects

Comment: I think it's not, I  add a breakpoint and it ignore it, I die(); inside and nothing happend in the list view. I can remove it if you want. And yes I add in my test class

Comment: can you please return a constant string to check it?
like 
return "check i am here ";
inside __toString?

Comment: It return the title on the entity from the DB in my list view, but in my edit form the breadcrumb return the "check i am here". This is why I think it's not call in the list view

Comment: In fact my problem is that the locale is not change when I click on the flag on the list view so it always return the default language. If I force to change language manually the correct language is display.